# ERROR: Unable to load the 'nvidia-drm' kernel module

Tags: server, nvidia, cuda

Trying to install Nvidia Driver using `cuda_8.0.61_375.26_linux.run`on Ubuntu 16.04 with `4.4.0-31-generic`kernel.

While installing I am getting the following errors:

`-> Would you like to register the kernel module sources with DKMS? This will allow DKMS to automatically build a new module, if you install
a different kernel later. (Answer: Yes)
-> Installing both new and classic TLS OpenGL libraries.
-> Installing both new and classic TLS 32bit OpenGL libraries.
-> Install NVIDIA's 32-bit compatibility libraries? (Answer: Yes)
-> Will install GLVND GLX client libraries.
-> Will install GLVND EGL client libraries.
-> Skipping GLX non-GLVND file: "libGL.so.375.26"
-> Skipping GLX non-GLVND file: "libGL.so.1"
-> Skipping GLX non-GLVND file: "libGL.so"
-> Skipping EGL non-GLVND file: "libEGL.so.375.26"
-> Skipping EGL non-GLVND file: "libEGL.so"
-> Skipping EGL non-GLVND file: "libEGL.so.1"
-> Skipping GLX non-GLVND file: "./32/libGL.so.375.26"
-> Skipping GLX non-GLVND file: "libGL.so.1"
-> Skipping GLX non-GLVND file: "libGL.so"
-> Skipping EGL non-GLVND file: "./32/libEGL.so.375.26"
-> Skipping EGL non-GLVND file: "libEGL.so"
-> Skipping EGL non-GLVND file: "libEGL.so.1"
-> Uninstalling the previous installation with /usr/bin/nvidia-uninstall.
Looking for install checker script at ./libglvnd_install_checker/check-libglvnd-install.sh
   executing: '/bin/sh ./libglvnd_install_checker/check-libglvnd-install.sh'...
   Checking for libglvnd installation.
   Checking libGLdispatch...
   Can't load library libGLdispatch.so.0: libGLdispatch.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Will install libglvnd libraries.
Will install libEGL vendor library config file to /usr/share/glvnd/egl_vendor.d
-> Searching for conflicting files:
-> done.
-> Installing 'NVIDIA Accelerated Graphics Driver for Linux-x86_64' (375.26):
   executing: '/sbin/ldconfig'...
-> done.
-> Driver file installation is complete.
-> Installing DKMS kernel module:
-> done.
ERROR: Unable to load the 'nvidia-drm' kernel module.
ERROR: Installation has failed.  Please see the file '/var/log/nvidia-installer.log' for details.  You may find suggestions on fixing instal
lation problems in the README available on the Linux driver download page at www.nvidia.com.`

Although on searching the file it, will present in the system under the location

```
/usr/lib32/libGLdispatch.so.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLdispatch.so.0
```

To fix the issue, I have set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` as well, but still facing the same issue. 
Any help to figure out the issue will be appreciated.